# How to conditions in Advance PDF HTML in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

Scenario:

On sales order there are two fields "Package Qty" and "Qty". Now on Sales order print the requirement is as follows:-

For Inventory Type = X, value should be from "Qty"
For Inventory Type = Y, Value should be form "Package Qty"

My question is how to handle this Scenario in Advance PDF HTML in NetSUite?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the actual field names and values you have so the following will need to be modified to suit, but it should give you the basic structure:

```
<#if inventorytype == 'X'>
    ${qty}
<#else>
    ${packageqty}
</#if>
```